# Expected value of conditional probability

Tags: probability

I'm working on a proof.

If X and Y are independent, then

$E(Y|X) = E(Y)$

X, Y are discrete random variables. And we assume that their joint marginal probability mass functions and expectations exists.

I'm pretty lost. My initial idea is to use the following definition:

$E(g(Y_1) | Y_2=y_2) = \sum_{all\;y_1} g(y_1)p(y_1|y_2)$

Should I use that, and if I should, how to proceed?

Hope you can help!

Comment: What does “d.r.v” mean? Aren't $X,Y$ independent?

Comment: @nejimban "discrete random variable". Yes X and Y are independent. Just added that to my question. Thank you!

Comment: So you are on a good track. You can compute $p(y_1|y_2)$ using independence, then the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the proof is quite immediate

$$E(Y|X)=\Sigma_y y\cdot p(y|x)=\Sigma_y y \cdot p(y)=E(Y)$$

this because by independence $p(y|x)=p(y)$